# how do I load a wordpress custom table on a custom plugin menu page

Tags: php, wordpress

To get the ball rolling I used this [sitepoint template](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-wp_list_table-to-create-wordpress-admin-tables/) to put together a custom table to use in a plugin on an admin options page...So far so good, but the stock plugin is designed to live on its own page...the thing is I need it to live on an existing page...though when I tried to move the code over into the specific file but it doesn't seem to fire at all.  There is more code of course, I'm just listing the relevant portion that creates the menu page in the admin menu....so I ask how do I add this into an existing page/action rather than create a new page?

```
...
class SP_Plugin {

  // class instance
  static $instance;

  // customer WP_List_Table object
  public $customers_obj;

  // class constructor
  public function __construct() {
    add_filter( 'set-screen-option', [ __CLASS__, 'set_screen' ], 10, 3 );
    add_action( 'admin_menu', [ $this, 'plugin_menu' ] );
  }


  public static function set_screen( $status, $option, $value ) {
    return $value;
  }

  public function plugin_menu() {

    $hook = add_menu_page(
      'Sitepoint WP_List_Table Example',
      'SP WP_List_Table',
      'manage_options',
      'wp_list_table_class',
      [ $this, 'plugin_settings_page' ]
    );

    add_action( "load-$hook", [ $this, 'screen_option' ] );

  }


  /**
   * Plugin settings page
   */
  public function plugin_settings_page() {
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
      <h2>WP_List_Table Class Example</h2>

      <div id="poststuff">
        <div id="post-body" class="metabox-holder columns-2">
          <div id="post-body-content">
            <div class="meta-box-sortables ui-sortable">
              <form method="post">
                <?php
                $this->customers_obj->prepare_items();
                $this->customers_obj->display(); ?>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br class="clear">
      </div>
    </div>
  <?php
  }

  /**
   * Screen options
   */
  public function screen_option() {

    $option = 'per_page';
    $args   = [
      'label'   => 'Records',
      'default' => 5,
      'option'  => 'customers_per_page'
    ];

    add_screen_option( $option, $args );

    $this->customers_obj = new Customers_List();
  }


  /** Singleton instance */
  public static function get_instance() {
    if ( ! isset( self::$instance ) ) {
      self::$instance = new self();
    }

    return self::$instance;
  }

}


add_action( 'plugins_loaded', function () {
  SP_Plugin::get_instance();
} );
```

The code used to initialize the my admin page for the plugin:

```
add_action('load_admin_faucet_page', 'plugin_settings_page');

function faucet_admin_page_container(){
require '../../../myfolder/myfile.php';
}
```

From there I thought it was going to be as simple as:

```
add_action('load_admin_faucet_page', 'plugin_settings_page')
```

But well...no dice and here we are.

Edit 1: as requested, here is the entire affected code portion that I *was* trying to load on myfile.php (not everything, just the class to extend wp_list_table - I would keep the actions on the main plugin file as it is now)...now I'm simply trying to keep it on the main plugin file and have it load on that specific page.

```
function load_admin_faucet_page(){
    add_menu_page('Faucet Settings', 'Faucet', 'manage_options', 'bitcoinfaucet-settings', 'faucet_admin_page_container', 'dashicons-welcome-view-site', 1);
}




function faucet_admin_page_container(){
require '../../myfile.php';
}  

...


add_action('admin_menu', 'load_admin_faucet_page');
add_action('load_admin_faucet_page', 'plugin_settings_page')



//allow redirection, even if my theme starts to send output to the browser
add_action('init', 'do_output_buffer');
function do_output_buffer() {
        ob_start();
}
...


if ( ! class_exists( 'WP_List_Table' ) ) {
  require_once('/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php' );
}

class Customers_List extends WP_List_Table {

  /** Class constructor */
  public function __construct() {

    parent::__construct( array(
      'singular' => __( 'Record', 'sp' ), //singular name of the listed records
      'plural'   => __( 'Records', 'sp' ), //plural name of the listed records
      'ajax'     => false //does this table support ajax?
    ) );

  }


  /**
   * Retrieve customers data from the database
   *
   * @param int $per_page
   * @param int $page_number
   *
   * @return mixed
   */
  public static function get_customers( $per_page = 5, $page_number = 1 ) {

    global $wpdb;

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table";

    if ( ! empty( $_REQUEST['orderby'] ) ) {
      $sql .= ' ORDER BY ' . esc_sql( $_REQUEST['orderby'] );
      $sql .= ! empty( $_REQUEST['order'] ) ? ' ' . esc_sql( $_REQUEST['order'] ) : ' ASC';
    }

    $sql .= " LIMIT $per_page";
    $sql .= ' OFFSET ' . ( $page_number - 1 ) * $per_page;


    $result = $wpdb->get_results( $sql, 'ARRAY_A' );

    return $result;
  }





 /**
   *  Associative array of columns
   *
   * @return array
   */
  function get_columns() {
    $columns = array(
      'cb'      => '<input type="checkbox" />',
      'id' => __( 'Id Number', 'sp' ),      
      'date' => __( 'Date', 'sp' ),
      'user'    => __( 'Address', 'sp' ),
      'amount' => __( 'Amount', 'sp'),
      'message'    => __( 'Message', 'sp' ),


    );

    return $columns;
  }


  /**
   * Columns to make sortable.
   *
   * @return array
   */
  public function get_sortable_columns() {
    $sortable_columns = array(
      'user' => array( 'user', false ),
      'date' => array( 'date', false ),
      'id' => array( 'id', true )
    );

    return $sortable_columns;
  }


  /**
   * Returns the count of records in the database.
   *
   * @return null|string
   */
  public static function record_count() {
    global $wpdb;

    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table";

    return $wpdb->get_var( $sql );
  }


  /** Text displayed when no customer data is available */
  public function no_items() {
    _e( 'No customers avaliable.', 'sp' );
  }


  /**
   * Render a column when no column specific method exist.
   *
   * @param array $item
   * @param string $column_name
   *
   * @return mixed
   */

  public function column_default( $item, $column_name ) {
    switch ( $column_name ) {
      case 'id':
      case 'user':
      case 'amount':
      case 'date':
      case 'message':
        return $item[ $column_name ];
      default:
        return print_r( $item, true ); //Show the whole array for troubleshooting purposes
    }
  }




  /**
   * Render the bulk edit checkbox
   *
   * @param array $item
   *
   * @return string
   */
  function column_cb( $item ) {
    return sprintf(
      '<input type="checkbox" name="my_CheckBoxes[]" value="%s" />', $item['id']

    );
  }





  /**
   * Method for name column
   *
   * @param array $item an array of DB data
   *
   * @return string
   */
  function column_name( $item ) {

    $delete_nonce = wp_create_nonce( 'sp_delete_customer' );
    $reset_nonce = wp_create_nonce( 'sp_reset_payouts' );

    $title = '<strong>' . $item['name'] . '</strong>';

    $actions = [
      'delete' => sprintf( '<a href="?page=%s&action=%s&customer=%s&_wpnonce=%s">Delete</a>', esc_attr( $_REQUEST['page'] ), 'delete', absint( $item['id'] ), $delete_nonce ),

      'reset' => sprintf( '<a href="?page=%s&action=%s&customer=%s&_wpnonce=%s">Reset</a>', esc_attr( $_REQUEST['page'] ), 'reset', absint( $item['id'] ), $reset_nonce )

    ];

    return $title . $this->row_actions( $actions );
  }




  /**
   * Returns an associative array containing the bulk action
   *
   * @return array
   */
  public function get_bulk_actions() {

    $actions = array(
      'bulk-delete' => 'Delete',
      'bulk-reset' => 'Reset'
    );

    return $actions;
  }


  /**
   * Handles data query and filter, sorting, and pagination.
   */
  public function prepare_items() {

    $this->_column_headers = $this->get_column_info();

    /** Process bulk action */
    $this->process_bulk_action();

    $per_page     = $this->get_items_per_page( 'customers_per_page', 5 );
    $current_page = $this->get_pagenum();
    $total_items  = self::record_count();

    $this->set_pagination_args( [
      'total_items' => $total_items, //WE have to calculate the total number of items
      'per_page'    => $per_page //WE have to determine how many items to show on a page
    ] );

    $this->items = self::get_customers( $per_page, $current_page );
  }



  /**
   * Delete a customer record.
   *
   * @param int $id customer ID
   */
  public static function delete_customer( $id ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $wpdb->delete(
      "table",
      array( 'id' => $id ),
      array('%d' )
    );
  }


  /**
   * Reset Message To Null.
   *
   * @param int $id customer ID
   */
  public static function reset_record( $id ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $wpdb->update(
      "table",
      array('message' => NULL),
      array('id' => $id )
    );
  }



  public function process_bulk_action() {

    //Detect when a bulk action is being triggered...
     if ( 'delete' === $this->current_action()){

      // In our file that handles the request, verify the nonce.
      $nonce = esc_attr( $_REQUEST['_wpnonce'] );

      if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'sp_delete_customer' ) ) {
        die( 'Go get a life script kiddies' );
      }
      else {
        self::delete_customer( absint( $_GET['customer'] ) );
        wp_redirect( esc_url( add_query_arg() ) );
        exit;
      }

}
    //Detect when a Reset is being triggered...
     if ( 'reset' === $this->current_action()){

      // In our file that handles the request, verify the nonce.
      $nonce = esc_attr( $_REQUEST['_wpnonce'] );

      if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'sp_reset_payouts' ) ) {
        die( 'Go get a life script kiddies' );
      }
      else {
        self::reset_record( absint ( $_GET['customer']));
        wp_redirect( esc_url( add_query_arg() ) );
        exit;
      }
}





    // // If the delete bulk action is triggered
    if ( ( isset( $_POST['action'] ) && $_POST['action'] == 'bulk-delete' )
         || ( isset( $_POST['action2'] ) && $_POST['action2'] == 'bulk-delete' )
    ) {

      $delete_ids = esc_sql( $_POST['my_CheckBoxes'] );

      // loop over the array of record IDs and delete them
      foreach ( $delete_ids as $id ) {
        self::delete_customer( $id );
      }
      wp_redirect( esc_url( add_query_arg() ) );
      exit;
    }


    //If the delete bulk action is triggered
    if ( ( isset( $_POST['action'] ) && $_POST['action'] == 'bulk-reset' )
         || ( isset( $_POST['action2'] ) && $_POST['action2'] == 'bulk-reset' )
    ) {

      $reset_ids = esc_sql( $_POST['my_CheckBoxes'] );

      // loop over the array of record IDs and delete them
      foreach ( $reset_ids as $id ) {
        self::reset_record( $id );

      }

      wp_redirect( esc_url( add_query_arg() ) );
      exit;
    }


  }

}





class SP_Plugin {

  // class instance
  static $instance;

  // customer WP_List_Table object
  public $customers_obj;

  // class constructor
  public function __construct() {
    add_filter( 'set-screen-option', [ __CLASS__, 'set_screen' ], 10, 3 );
    add_action( 'admin_menu', [ $this, 'plugin_menu' ] );
  }


  public static function set_screen( $status, $option, $value ) {
    return $value;
  }

  public function plugin_menu() {

    $hook = add_menu_page(
      'Sitepoint WP_List_Table Example',
      'SP WP_List_Table',
      'manage_options',
      'wp_list_table_class',
      [ $this, 'plugin_settings_page' ]
    );

    add_action( "load-$hook", [ $this, 'screen_option' ] );

  }


  /**
   * Plugin settings page
   */
  public function plugin_settings_page() {
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
      <h2>WP_List_Table Class Example</h2>

      <div id="poststuff">
        <div id="post-body" class="metabox-holder columns-2">
          <div id="post-body-content">
            <div class="meta-box-sortables ui-sortable">
              <form method="post">
                <?php
                $this->customers_obj->prepare_items();
                $this->customers_obj->display(); ?>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br class="clear">
      </div>
    </div>
  <?php
  }

  /**
   * Screen options
   */
  public function screen_option() {

    $option = 'per_page';
    $args   = [
      'label'   => 'Records',
      'default' => 5,
      'option'  => 'customers_per_page'
    ];

    add_screen_option( $option, $args );

    $this->customers_obj = new Customers_List();
  }


  /** Singleton instance */
  public static function get_instance() {
    if ( ! isset( self::$instance ) ) {
      self::$instance = new self();
    }

    return self::$instance;
  }

}


add_action( 'plugins_loaded', function () {
  SP_Plugin::get_instance();
} );
```

Comment: the issue seems to be your custom hooks but yet you have not showed your code that uses the hooks i.e, do_action......your q is not answerable as is!

Comment: could you elaborate.  I have this action load_admin_faucet_page....that's the page I wanted to show my table on...I thought I call the table using `SP_Plugin::get_instance();` to do that I tried to simply copy my entire class and supporting functions on that `myfile.php`  I was against posting my tome of 427LOC hold on

Comment: yes the hook is load-(page) , so unless your page is called "admin_faucet_page" it will never be fired, but it seems to me like you are trying to use a function name as a hook?

Comment: my page I'm trying to load it on  `...admin.php?page=bitcoinfaucet-settings`